# CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h not found when build webkit on windows

Tags: c++, webkit

When I try to build webkit on Windows 10, I got the following errors, because can not found CoreGraphics and CoreFoundation header files.

I had already installed all require programs on this page (https://webkit.org/webkit-on-windows/#installing-developer-tools), including iTunes(12.10.9.3).

Maybe it is missing Apple Application Support? but I can't found it in iTunes. Can anyone help me?

```
D:\Workspace\webkit\Tools\ImageDiff\cg\PlatformImageCG.cpp(29,10): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件: “CoreGraphics/CGBitmapC
ontext.h”: No such file or directory [D:\Workspace\webkit\WebKitBuild\Release\Tools\ImageDiff\ImageDiffLib.vcxproj]
  Assertions.cpp
  CrossThreadCopier.cpp
  CrossThreadTaskHandler.cpp
  DateMath.cpp
  FileSystem.cpp
  GregorianDateTime.cpp
  HexNumber.cpp
  JSONValues.cpp
D:\Workspace\webkit\Source\WTF\wtf/RetainPtr.h(32,10): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件: “CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h”:
No such file or directory (编译源文件 D:\Workspace\webkit\Source\WTF\wtf\HexNumber.cpp) [D:\Workspace\webkit\WebKitBuild\Rel
ease\Source\WTF\wtf\WTF.vcxproj]
  Language.cpp
D:\Workspace\webkit\Source\WTF\wtf/RetainPtr.h(32,10): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件: “CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h”:
No such file or directory (编译源文件 D:\Workspace\webkit\Source\WTF\wtf\Assertions.cpp) [D:\Workspace\webkit\WebKitBuild\Re
lease\Source\WTF\wtf\WTF.vcxproj]
D:\Workspace\webkit\Source\WTF\wtf/RetainPtr.h(32,10): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件: “CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h”:
No such file or directory (编译源文件 D:\Workspace\webkit\Source\WTF\wtf\CrossThreadCopier.cpp) [D:\Workspace\webkit\WebKitB
uild\Release\Source\WTF\wtf\WTF.vcxproj]
```

Answer (score 0):

Those header files are included in WebKitSupportLibrary.zip. Did you download WebKitSupportLibrary.zip and put it in the top source directory?